# Different results from random effects plm (R) and xtreg (Stata)

Tags: r, panel-data, stata

I'm trying to convert the analysis from an old research paper from Stata to R. However, I ran into a problem that I have been unable to fix.

When I compare the coefficients from the two programs, they are not the same, even though the input is the same. I found this thread which describes a similar problem but for fixed effects:
[Difference between fixed effects models in R (plm) and Stata (xtreg)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/difference-between-fixed-effects-models-in-r-plm-and-stata-xtreg)

However, the answer there gets a lot smaller difference than I get, accounting just for the difference in how `plm` and `xtreg` handle year effects.

For example, using the V-dem v9 Country-Year Full+Others dataset https://www.v-dem.net/en/data/data-version-9/, I ran this:

```
    library(plm)
Vdemv9 <- readRDS("./Country_Year_V-dem_Full+others_R_v9/V-Dem-CY-Full+Others-v9.rds")

model2 <- plm(v2x_polyarchy ~ v2elembaut+v2elrgstry,
                data = Vdemv9,
                model = "random",
                index = c("country_id","year"))
    summary(model2)

## Results:
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 0.3735057  0.0059080  63.221 < 2.2e-16 ***
v2elembaut  0.1105280  0.0020646  53.534 < 2.2e-16 ***
v2elrgstry  0.0600031  0.0023033  26.051 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Stata gives me the following results:

```
xtset country_id year, yearly
xtreg v2x_polyarchy v2elembaut v2elrgstry

## Results
v2x_polyar~y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  v2elembaut |   .1105945   .0020701    53.43   0.000     .1065372    .1146518
  v2elrgstry |   .0601527   .0023079    26.06   0.000     .0556292    .0646761
       _cons |   .3733406   .0062298    59.93   0.000     .3611304    .3855508
```

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is this something I need to worry about? The difference is small at only .0000665 for the coefficient for `v2elembaut`, but I would have expected it to not be there at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data are unbalanced, you will get different results from `plm` and Stata for the Swamy-Arora methods for random effects. For balanced data, you should get identical estimates.

This difference is due to a slight variation in the implementation: see `plm`'s vignette
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/B_plmFunction.html, section "Unbalanced Panels" and especially the paper by Cottrell (2017) mentioned there with more details (and Stata's documentation for `xtreg`, but it is discussed in Cottrell (2017)).

Best to my knowledge, `plm` and EViews are the only major implementations that use the formulae as given by Baltagi/Chang (1994) for the unbalanced case of Swamy-Arora per default. Stata and gretl use a slightly different implementation, also when using Stata's `sa` option to specifially request Swamy-Arora. However, it is possible to replicate Stata's results (using the `sa` option) with `plm` (see plm`s vignette).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Been reading the vignette several times now, and experimenting between Stata and R, yet I only manage to get the different lower, not exact. Using "random.models = c("within", "between")", which I understod references the formula used by Stata, I get the coef 0.1105355, while Stata directly gives me 0.1105945, a slight slight difference. However, if I understand the vignette, both formulae are acceptable?

Comment: Did you use Stata's `sa` option? Anyway I would not worry about a difference in the 5th digit.

Comment: I did not, but thanks very much! :) Knowing why there is a difference will suffice for masters level in political science!